# How do I add +string within a text?

Tags: string, readline, console.writeline

I would like to know how to add [+line] within a Console.WriteLine / Console.Write.

For example:

```
string line;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter one or more lines of text (press 'gg' to exit):");
    do
    {
       Console.Write(" ");
        line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line != "b")
            Console.WriteLine(" Sorry, you wrote **???**, which is wrong. \n Try again." +line);
       else
           Console.WriteLine("u rock");
    }
           while ( line != "gg") ;
```

I want to add [+line] in the middle of the sentence, where the question marks are.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) is your best bet (assuming you're on C# 6 or above). Remember the $ at the start of the string:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, you wrote {line}, which is wrong. \n Try again.");
```

You could have also used to separate strings added together, though this is a bit more clunky:

```
Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you wrote " +  line + ", which is wrong. \n Try again.");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried writing **{+line}**, but didn't know it is without the **+** and I had to use **$** at  the beginning.
Thank you very much! 
I have to wait more 10 mins to approve the answer, though...

Comment: Can you also tell me from the given code, how to read from the console without adding a new line with the entered text? I mean, I write a word and after i press Enter it forces the Console.WriteLine directly without registering in the console which characters i wrote?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the characters you typed in to show up, like you were entering a password?

Comment: [Picture here](https://imgur.com/a/ixWnK)
They can show up when i write them, but I prefer not to be recorded on a new raw when i press Enter. I want to receive directly the Console.WriteLine message after i press Enter.